# Print pyramid pattern in java

Tags: java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                int i,j,k;
        for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                for(k=3;k>0;k--)
                {
                    System.out.println(" ");
                }
                System.out.println("*");
               }
            System.out.println("\n");

        }

    }

}
```

output is :

```
*





*



*





*



*



*





*



*



*



*


BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Either use `println()` or use a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: Again someone who lets doing the homework by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
         for(int j=0;j<5-i;j++) {
             System.out.print(" ");
         }
        for(int k=0;k<=i;k++) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
     * 
    * * 
   * * * 
  * * * * 
 * * * * *
```

Just for your knowledge `System.out.println` will print on a new line where `System.out.print` will print in the same line.